# PHP is not recieving JSON data from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to use ajaxFIleUpload in my website. I am not recieving JSON data send by JavaScript to PHP. I am stuck at this point. File Uploading is ok but i am not able to recieve any post values. My jQuery function is

```
$(function() {

    $(document).on("submit", "#upload_file", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajaxFileUpload({
            url             :base_url + 'payments/uploadPaymentSlip/',
            secureuri       :false,
            fileElementId   :'userfile',
            type        : 'POST',
            data: { paymentFormInputAmount: 'asdasd' },
            success : function (data, status)
            {
                if(data.status != 'error')
                {
                    $('#files').html('<p>Reloading files...</p>');
                    //refresh_files();
                    $('#files').val('');
                }
                alert(data.msg);
            },
           dataType: 'json'
        });

    });
});
```

My PHP Function is

```
function uploadPaymentSlip() {
    $status = "";
    $msg = "";
    $file_element_name = 'userfile';

    $status = "error";
    // checking whether json value shows in php or not
    // $_POST['paymentFormInputAmount'] is also not working
    $msg = $_POST['paymentFormInputAmount'];

    if ($status != "error") {
        $config['upload_path'] = realpath( APPPATH . '../uploads/paymentSlip' );
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
        $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name)) {
            $status = 'error';
            $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
        }
        else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            // $file_id = $this->files_model->insert_file($data['file_name'], $_POST['title']);
            if($file_id) {
                $status = "success";
                $msg = "File successfully uploaded";
            }
            else {
                unlink($data['full_path']);
                $status = "error";
                $msg = "Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again.";
            }
        }
        @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
    }

    echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
}
```

Comment: How are you calling your PHP function `uploadPaymentSlip`?

Comment: url             :base_url + 'payments/uploadPaymentSlip/', This is part calls PHP function. I think calling php function is correct because beside getting json values, upload is successfull.

Answer (score 1):

`type: 'json'` must be `type: 'POST'`

and you should add:

```
contentType: 'json',
dataType: 'json'
```

as parameter to `$.ajaxFileUpload`

`contentType` means you are sending your data as `json`.

`dataType` means you are expecting result as type of `json.`

Comment: I have changed according to your suggestion. I am getting 'false' instead of 'asdasd'

Comment: You are getting false because you are expecting data as `json` in your php script. You don't seem to use `$_POST` as a `json` object so, I suggest you to remove `contentType: 'json'` and change `data: { 'paymentFormInputAmount': 'asdasd' },` as `data: { paymentFormInputAmount: 'asdasd' },`

Comment: not working. still getting false. Please my edited jquery part. I have changed according to your suggestion.

Comment: Can you share which plugin exactly you are using for ajax upload? There are plenty of them, some of them may send data in different way. By the way, are you getting file in php script and do you want to send extra data with POST?

Comment: I need to send extra data with the post. I need to get payment details using jSon, which I am not getting actually. [http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684] is the link of plugin that I am using.

Comment: I can't get further details about sending extra data in this plugin and it seems that this plugin only sends file contents with ajax request. Therefore I suggest you to use reqular `$.ajax()` function. There are lots of information and tutorials about how to use it.